# Image of $\rm{lim}^1$ functor

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

In category of abelian groups, we know that

— values of $\rm{lim}^1$ on countable systems are precisely cotorsion groups

— values of $\rm{lim}^1$ on systems of finitely generated groups are of the form $\rm{Ext}^1(A, \Bbb Z)$ with $A$ flat

— every group is a $\rm{lim}^1$ of a system of cardinality $\Omega$

Can these be generalized in some way to an arbitrary abelian category? (Probably, of finite global dimension, otherwise there's little hope for anything similar)

Comment: Isn't the theory of cotorsion pairs a vast generalization of these cases?

Comment: Maybe: I do not see how one can prove either second or third statement not using an explicit classification of divisible abelian groups. If you can, I'll be pleased to know how.